# Write a program which will input a 4 digit number from the user and then print the first and 2nd last digit of the number?

Tags: c#

Write a program which will input a 4 digit number from the user and then print the first and 2nd last digit of the number
....
I can reverse the 4 numbers but can't do this..

Comment: Try modulo arithmetics: `/ 100` and `% 100`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide code and explain what you tried so far

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entered number is a four digit number.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num, sum = 0, r,pos = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (num != 0)
        { 
            pos++;
            r = num % 10;
            num = num / 10;

            if(pos == 0)||(pos==2){
                Console.WriteLine("Digit at"+ pos + "is : "+r);
            }
        }           
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string data, firstDigit, secondLastDigit = string.Empty;
        Console.Write("Enter a 4 digit number : ");

        data = Console.ReadLine();
        while (data.Length != 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data + " is not a 4 digit number");
            Console.Write("Re-enter a 4 digit number : ");
            data = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        firstDigit = data.Substring(0, 1);
        secondLastDigit = data.Substring(data.Length - 2, 1);

        Console.Write("First digit : " + firstDigit + " | " + "Second last digit : " + secondLastDigit);
        Console.ReadLine();
```